# import class in asp.net inline codeing

Tags: vb.net, inline-code

I create a class SharedClass.vb in my project . And i want to import that SharedClass.vb on my aspx page and want to use that class on my aspx file.  How can i do that .  i Try this but not success

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="ipmseattle.Web._default5" Explicit="false" %>
<%@ Import Namespace = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="SharedClass" %>
```

And this is the function that i created

```
 Public Class SharedClass

    Public Shared Function encode(ByVal x)
        x = x & " "
        encode = Replace(x, "'", "''")
        encode = Replace(encode, ";", "")
        encode = Replace(encode, "--", "")
        encode = Replace(encode, "({", "")
        encode = Replace(encode, "/*", "")
    encode = Trim(encode)
    End Function
End Class
```

i am using inline coding . Where the code part is on my .aspx file . Here i am using that class

```
if request("date") <> "" then
if isdate(request("date")) then
            SQLADDON = "event_start_date >= '" & encode(Request("date")) & "' and event_start_date < '" & encode(formatmysqldate(DateAdd("d", 1, Request("date")))) & "' and event_title like '%Apple%' "
else
```

Regards

Comment: @abhitalks this is website i am using .aspx file

Comment: in that case put your class library inside `app_code` folder. it should be then available throughout the website without importing. btw: you import namespaces not classes.

Comment: @abhitalks how can i use that class can you please explain

Comment: @A.Goutam create your class library and save the .cs or .vb file inside the `app_code` folder. then you just call the methods like this: `ClassName.MethodName` whereever you want in the entire website. any content inside `app_code` will get JIT comiled along with the rest of the website and will be available within the same namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are specifiying a class name in your impor sentence, and it expects a namespace.
Replace

```
<%@ Import Namespace="SharedClass" %>
```

with

```
<%@ Import Namespace="SharedClassNamespace" %>
```

Comment: Does your proyect compile? Wich is exactly the error message you receive?